# What requirements must be met to use complex steps on a component?

Tags: openmdao

What requirements must be met by a component to use complex steps to approximate partial derivatives on the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the function must be defined in a way such that it can accept complex input and provide a corresponding output.  *Many* of the functions in `numpy` support this.  One notable exception is `arctan2`.

You can demonstrate this for yourself, lets use np.sin and compute its derivative with complex-step:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 3.231662
>>> np.sin(x)
-0.08994761472861613
>>> dx = 0+1E-16j
>>> # The complex step solution
>>> (np.sin(x+dx) - np.sin(x))/1.0E-16j
(-0.995946497862527-0j)
>>> # The analytic solution
>>> np.cos(x)
-0.995946497862527
```

Basically, the math in your component needs to contain functions that handle complex numbers cleanly without truncating the imaginary portion.  If you ever do a table lookup using only a real number, for instance, that would mean the response doesn't change if the input's imaginary part changes.

Secondly, the functions must be *complex analytic*.  This basically means they are continuously differentiable in both directions of the complex plane.  Absolute value is one example of a function that is not complex analytic.  You can read more about complex analytic functions here:  https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Complex_analytic_function

Comment: Another situation that prevents use of complex-step method is if your analysis relies on complex arithmetic itself. For example some electrical engineering rely on complex numbers, and hence can't be complex-stepped for derivatives